# Why is comparison between number and numeric argument not working in \ifnum and \ifdim conditionals?

Tags: conditionals, sourcecode, variable, comparison

I was modifying `\@ssect` command to edit `\section*` appearance. First I passed a further argument to `\@ssect`

```
\def\@ssect#1#2#3#4#5#6{%...
```

then I edited the dependencies in `\@startsection` by modifying `\@ssect{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}` to `\@ssect{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#2}`, since I would like to pass to `\@ssect` also the sectioning level, so that I can use it to have different styles conditionally. 
The problem comes when I try to put something like

```
\ifnum#5<2
    %...
\else
    %...
\fi
```

to use a conditional expression using the level value which is now given by `#5` (in `\@ssect#1#2#3#4#5#6`), as one can easily see by printing it. 
I tried with different `if` conditionals, like `\ifdim` and I get always the same error at the very first 
`\section*`.

```
Package hyperref Warning: old toc file detected, not used; run LaTeX again.

./MYFILE.tex:12: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.12    \section*{NAME}

?
```

While for example if I use the argument `#1` which is already a length (actually `\z@`) `\ifdim` command does not complain. I then tried to add a measure unit to the argument with `\ifdim #5 pt < 2pt`, but the same error occurred. 
What is going on here?

## mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
    \def\doublerfill{\hrule width \hsize \kern .5mm \hrule width \hsize height 1.3pt }
    \def\@seccntformat#1{\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}
    \def\@startsection#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
        \if@noskipsec \leavevmode \fi
        \par
        \@tempskipa #4\relax
        \@afterindenttrue
        \ifdim \@tempskipa <\z@
            \@tempskipa -\@tempskipa \@afterindentfalse
        \fi
        \if@nobreak
            \everypar{}%
        \else
            \addpenalty\@secpenalty\addvspace\@tempskipa
        \fi
        \@ifstar
            {\@ssect{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#2}}%
            {\@dblarg{\@sect{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}}}
    \def\@ssect#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
        \@tempskipa #3\relax
        \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@
            \begingroup
                #4{%
                    \@hangfrom{\hskip #1}%
                        \interlinepenalty \@M #6\@@par}%
            \endgroup
            \ifnum#5<2
                foo1
            \else
                foo2
            \fi
        \else
            \def\@svsechd{#4{\hskip #1\relax #6}}%
        \fi
        \@xsect{#3}}
\makeatother
%
    \usepackage{hyperref}
%
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section*{Foo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: please provide a test file that shows the problem.

Comment: Remember you also have to replace all occurrences of `#5` by `#6` in `\@ssect`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In preparing the `mwe` I discovered the problem being related with `hyperref`, I'll post immediately the incriminated `mwe`. Looks that if I cut the package away problem disappears.

Comment: that is hardly surprising hyperref has to know the structure of section headings, it does `\let\H@old@ssect\@ssect
\def\@ssect#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \Hy@MakeCurrentHrefAuto{section*}%
....`  with the code assuming the existing argument structure

Comment: But why the error does not display if I don't make the comparison? I mean, without the conditional everything seems to work fine...

Comment: @GiuTeX you get lucky? the code is basically broken after you load hyperref as `\@ssect` is redefined again back to only having 5 arguments

Comment: Add `\def\temp{#5}\show\temp` to your code (before the comparision) and you will see why.

Comment: @GiuTeX: Look at the definitions of `\@sect` and `\@ssect` inside [`hyperref.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/hyperref.dtx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hyperref` needs to patch section commands to add link anchors, it redefines `\@sect` to once again have 5 arguments, which means that basically the code does not do anything reasonable in that case. It may avoid giving an error without the added ifnum but it doesn't work as intended.

If you want to do this you would need to make a matching change in the hyperref version

```
\let\H@old@ssect\@ssect
\def\@ssect#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \Hy@MakeCurrentHrefAuto{section*}%
  \setlength{\Hy@SectionHShift}{#1}%
  \begingroup
    \toks@{\H@old@ssect{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}%
    \toks\tw@\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\Hy@SectionAnchorHref\expandafter{\@currentHref}%
      #5%
    }%
  \edef\x{\endgroup
    \the\toks@{\the\toks\tw@}%
  }\x
}
```

Comment: So basically I just need to add a sixth argument to the `hyperref`'s section and swap `#5` with `#6` there? Thanks for your expertise and knowledge!

Comment: @GiuTeX yes but lots of other packages also patch in to the sectioning commands, nameref, cleverref etc all need to know where to pick up the name of the section, if you are brave enough to redefine a core latex command then you need to be brave enough to follow through and make adjustments to the entire stack of latex contributions that sit above those core commands.

Comment: :) No, I do not pretend to be so brave, I'm just intrigued by the tons of things one discovers in looking and (perhaps in a very stupid way like me) modifying source commands. It was for a single file for which I don't need so much precision. Anyway I really prefer to use the less package I need (for what I need...). I won't anyway make such big changes in the future, I perfectly understand it just creates weird pathologies, I just use these things as a gym for better LaTeXing. Do you advise against sectioning modification in general or you think that minor editing can be done? Thanks for all.

Comment: @GiuTeX you never really gave any top level description of the intended effect. Almost certainly there is a less aggressive way to implement whatever the intended behaviour is than to redefine the core sectioning code that is used in almost every latex document and assumed by hundreds of packages and classes on ctan:-)

Comment: that said, for a one-off document where you only have a fixed small list of possible interactions, it is not necessarily a bad idea. @GiuTeX